# MacBook starts up but is unresponsive

Tags: macos, boot, macbook

I have an original MacBook A1181, which I bought second hand last year.

Up until recently it had been working fine, I had had to upgrade the RAM to 4 GB and buy a new battery but had no other issues. Recently when I turned my MacBook on it boots up fine, however it is completely unresponsive after loading everything for several minutes.

I can move the mouse around the screen but cannot select anything with the cursor nor do any of the function keys or keyboard shortcuts work. After several minutes however everything works fine.

This is rather inconvenient as I would prefer to not have to wait five minutes after turning my MacBook on before I can use it.

I was wondering what might cause this temporary unresponsiveness and if there was a way I could fix the problem?

Comment: @EntropyWins Questions about Macs and OS X are on topic here, and these questions should stay here. Please don't send users elsewhere when their question is fine to stay. For more info see [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/). Thanks!

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Can you check *Console.app* for any relevant messages? If not, just dump everything you can find to [Pastie](http://pastie.com/) and we might be able to see something. Does your user log in automatically? Are there any applications you installed that start up automatically? Can you try creating another user account and see if the problem persists there?

Comment: I'm on Snow Leopard OS, yeah I log in automatically, I checked start up applications and there is only like one and that loads before it becomes unresponsive. I will try creating another user now.

Comment: With automatic login turned off and a new account, it takes a long time to load the login screen, but then after login works perfectly.

Comment: Good to know – at least you could start moving to that new user profile. Digging to the root of the problem might be time-consuming, Console output would help troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Logging in to either profile works fine after the long period of time to load the login menu. I will check console output.